Find out runtime/time since start of application?
The application needs to know how long it is running/when it was started.
Is that possible with some standard existing Java objects inside of the JDK?
Or do I need to get a timestamp at startup or check process-list of the OS?

On Java 9+ you can use ProcessHandle.Info::startInstant():

Returns the start time of the process.

Example:
public static Duration uptime() {
  return ProcessHandle.current()                    // ProcessHandle
      .info()                                       // ProcessHandle.Info
      .startInstant()                               // Optional<Instant>
      .map(i -> Duration.between(i, Instant.now())) // Optional<Duration>
      .orElseThrow();                               // Duration
}


You can use RuntimeMXBean.getUptime()

long getUptime()
Returns the uptime of the Java virtual machine in milliseconds.

var runtimeMX = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
var uptimeInMillis = runtimeMX.getUptime();

